# Is there a maximum Bloodline?

Tags: infinity-blade

Do the Bloodlines continue after level 20? And past level -10 in the other direction (Negative Bloodlines) with the Dark Mech? How far?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the bloodlines will continue in both directions. However, there's really no point in going to negative 11 since you unlock the Dark Mech suit on negative 10 to use in positive bloodlines. (Along with an achievement!)